# How to delete all .css files created by Live Sass compiler extension in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am working on a very large project and accidentally clicked on the button of the Live Sass compiler plugin in VSCode and it automatically created me hundreds of css files.
Is there a quick way to undo and delete all files?

***Edit:* Finally I filtered all the files in the project folder by creation date, and deleted all the files created by mistake**

Comment: You can try `rm *.css` in bash/powershell, but beware that all css files on the current directory will be deleted.

Comment: Do you have any css files which you don't want to delete?

Answer (score 1):

you can change liveSass css path in vscode and delete any time you want:

```
{    
  "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
  {
    "format": "expanded",
    "extensionName": ".css",
    "savePath": "/dist/css/"     
  }

],

  "editor.minimap.enabled": true,
  "liveSassCompile.settings.generateMap": false
}
```